# JT400 - Display content of a SpooledFile

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

I try to display the content of a SpooledFile with the library jt40.
I use this code :

```
public static void printJogLog(AS400 as400, Job j) {
    SpooledFile spooledFile = new SpooledFile(as400, "QPJOBLOG", 1, j.getName(), j.getUser(), j.getNumber());

    try {
        PrintParameterList printParms = new PrintParameterList();
        printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_WORKSTATION_CUST_OBJECT, "/QSYS.LIB/QWPDEFAULT.WSCST");
        printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_MFGTYPE, "*WSCST");
        PrintObjectPageInputStream is = spooledFile.getPageInputStream(printParms);
        PrintObjectTransformedInputStream in = spooledFile.getTransformedInputStream(printParms);

        byte[] buf = new byte[32767];
        StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do {
            bytesRead = in.read(buf);
            if (bytesRead != -1) { // process the spooled file data.
                sbuf.append(new String(buf, 1, bytesRead, "CP936"));
            }
        } while (bytesRead != -1);
        System.out.println(sbuf.toString());

        BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));
        String data = "";
        String pageSpool = "";
        while ((data = d.readLine()) != null) {
            pageSpool += data + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(pageSpool);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It prints the content of the SpooledFile but I have problems with special characters.
I obtain things like this :

> CPF412C    Echappement             40   12/02/15  17:08:33,699347  QTAERR       QSYS        00EA     QSRVALDV    QSYS        *STMT
>                                        Module de destination . . . :   QSRVALDV
>                                        Proc俤ure de destination  . :   OPENVOLUME
>                                        Instruction . . . . . . . . :   3716
>                                        Message . . . . :   Cartouche PPRD05 introuvable
>                                        Cause . . . . . : La cartouche PPRD05 a 倀� indiqu俥 pour l'unit� de
>                                          bandoth妐ue TAPVTL01, mais elle n'existe pas dans l'unit� TAPVTL01. Que
>                                          faire . . . : Effectuez l'une des op俽ations suivantes, puis renouvelez
>                                          votre demande : -- Sp俢ifiez un identificateur de cartouche correct ou
>                                          ins俽ez la cartouche dans la biblioth妐ue. La cartouche en a peut-坱re 倀�
>                                          retir俥. -- Si vous avez indiqu� VOL(*MOUNT), l'identificateur de la
>                                          cartouche n'a peut-坱re pas 倀� d倀ermin�. Indiquez une cartouche pour le
>                                          param妕re VOL. -- Si l'incident persiste, mettez l'unit� hors fonction, puis
>                                          remettez-la en fonction � l'aide de la commande VRYCFG (Changer l'倀at d'une
>                                          configuration) en indiquant le param妕re RESET(*YES). -- Si la commande
>                                          ADDTAPCTG (Ajouter une cartouche de bande) a 倀� 俶ise, il se peut que la
>                                          cartouche ait 倀� retir俥 du guichet en libre-service avant son utilisation.

I think I need to set some parameters for the PrintObjet but I don't know how to choose the good parameters and values.

Can someone explain me how to know which parameter I need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here :
http://fixunix.com/ibm-as400/258696-java-read-french-spool.html

I modify my function like this :

```
public static void printJobLog2(AS400 as400, Job job) {
    SpooledFile spooledFile = new SpooledFile(as400, "QPJOBLOG", 1, job.getName(), job.getUser(), job.getNumber());
    PrintParameterList printParms = new PrintParameterList();
    printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_WORKSTATION_CUST_OBJECT, "/QSYS.LIB/QWPDEFAULT.WSCST");
    printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_MFGTYPE, "*WSCST");
    try {
        InputStreamReader in = new
                InputStreamReader(spooledFile.getTransformedInputStream(printParms), "cp850");
        char[] buf = new char[32767];
        StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
        if (in.ready()) {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                sbuf.append(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sbuf.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now it works.

> CPF412C    Echappement             40   16/02/15  08:55:14,184776  QTAERR       QSYS        00EA     QSRVALDV    QSYS        *STMT
>                                        Module de destination . . . :   QSRVALDV
>                                        Procédure de destination  . :   OPENVOLUME
>                                        Instruction . . . . . . . . :   3716
>                                        Message . . . . :   Cartouche SCOH07 introuvable
>                                        Cause . . . . . : La cartouche SCOH07 a été indiquée pour l'unité de
>                                          bandothèque TAPVTL01, mais elle n'existe pas dans l'unité TAPVTL01.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a CCSID mis-match.  Are you sure you want to open the InputStreamReader with UTF8?  Try `BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));` and let the machine decide the character set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I try to remove the "UTF8" but it doesn't change anything.

As you say, I think this is may be a problem of CCSID.
The CCSID of my spoolfile is 297, so I try to set it to 297 in my program but it doesn't correct the issue.